# Trait to extend iterators with parallelized mapping function

Tags: multithreading, rust

Working on a project of mine, I wanted to parallelize mapping operations on an input stream. I found [pariter](https://crates.io/crates/pariter) on crates.io but it did not fit my needs, because its generic's bounds require the iterator to be `'static`, which is not what I want (the iterators I work with are not `'static`).

I am not too experienced with parallel programming, since mostly I let frameworks do the heavy lifting for me, but here I felt compelled to write the needed parallelization on my own, since I did not find anything fitting my needs.

```
[package]
name = "threaded-map"
authors = ["Richard Neumann <mail@richard-neumann.de>"]
description = "Encode bytes as ANSI background colors"
license = "MIT"
homepage = "https://github.com/conqp/threaded-map/"
repository = "https://github.com/conqp/threaded-map/"
readme = "README.md"
documentation = "https://docs.rs/threaded-map"
keywords = [ "threaded", "mapping"]
version = "0.1.1"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
threadpool = "1.8.1"
```

`src/lib.rs`:

````rust
use std::sync::mpsc::{channel, Receiver};
use threadpool::{Builder, ThreadPool};

pub trait ThreadedMappable<F, O>
where
    Self: Iterator + Sized,
    F: Fn(<Self as Iterator>::Item) -> O + Send + Clone,
    <Self as Iterator>::Item: Send,
    O: Send + Sync,
{
    /// Maps items of an iterator in parallel while conserving their order
    /// # Examples
    /// ```
    /// use threaded_map::ThreadedMappable;
    /// let items = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    /// let target: Vec<_> = items.iter().map(i32::to_string).collect();
    ///
    /// let result: Vec<_> = items
    ///     .into_iter()
    ///     .parallel_map(|item| item.to_string(), None)
    ///     .collect();
    ///
    /// assert_eq!(result, target);
    /// ```
    fn parallel_map(self, f: F, num_threads: Option<usize>) -> ThreadedMap<Self, F, O> {
        ThreadedMap::new(self, f, num_threads)
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct ThreadedMap<I, F, O>
where
    I: Iterator,
    F: Fn(<I as Iterator>::Item) -> O + 'static,
    <I as Iterator>::Item: 'static,
    O: Send + 'static,
{
    iterator: I,
    function: F,
    thread_pool: ThreadPool,
    window: Vec<O>,
}

impl<I, F, O> ThreadedMap<I, F, O>
where
    I: Iterator,
    F: Fn(<I as Iterator>::Item) -> O + Send + Clone,
    <I as Iterator>::Item: Send,
    O: Send + Sync,
{
    pub fn new(iterator: I, function: F, num_threads: Option<usize>) -> Self {
        Self {
            iterator,
            function,
            thread_pool: num_threads.map_or_else(|| Builder::new().build(), ThreadPool::new),
            window: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    fn send_items(&mut self) -> Receiver<(usize, O)> {
        let (tx, rx) = channel::<(usize, O)>();

        for (index, item) in (0..self.thread_pool.max_count())
            .map_while(|_| self.iterator.next())
            .enumerate()
        {
            let tx = tx.clone();
            let f = self.function.clone();
            self.thread_pool.execute(move || {
                tx.send((index, (f)(item)))
                    .expect("channel will be there waiting for the pool");
            });
        }

        rx
    }
}

impl<I, F, O> Iterator for ThreadedMap<I, F, O>
where
    I: Iterator,
    F: Fn(<I as Iterator>::Item) -> O + Send + Clone,
    <I as Iterator>::Item: Send,
    O: Send + Sync,
{
    type Item = O;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if let Some(item) = self.window.pop() {
            return Some(item);
        }

        let rx = self.send_items();
        let mut window: Vec<_> = rx.iter().collect();

        if window.is_empty() {
            return None;
        }

        window.sort_by(|(lhs, _), (rhs, _)| rhs.cmp(lhs));
        self.window = window.into_iter().map(|(_, item)| item).collect();
        self.window.pop()
    }
}

impl<I, F, O> ThreadedMappable<F, O> for I
where
    I: Iterator,
    F: Fn(<I as Iterator>::Item) -> O + Send + Clone,
    <I as Iterator>::Item: Send,
    O: Send + Sync,
{
}
````

The code currently *works* [with the program I wrote it for](https://github.com/conqp/ansi-color-codec/blob/ad0964ed422dadabfbdcdebca5f1776166a133dc/src/codec.rs#L83).

However, I'd like to have feedback as to whether my code is idiomatic and whether it may have some flaws, especially regarding its multithreading efficiency.

Comment: The classic library for those tasks in Rust is [`rayon`](https://docs.rs/rayon), which has _many_ more downloads than the obscure library you've found and also doesn't require `'static`.